# i18n Vue3 read or change locale

Tags: internationalization, vuejs3, composition

I'm kinda new to Vue3 or clientside development in general and I'm tasked to read or change the global locale from i18n. But according to the documentation I should be able to use the $i18n variable in my component, but it tells me it is undefined.

This is my i18n config:

```
    import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
    import en from "./locales/en.json";
    import nl from "./locales/nl.json";
    
    const i18n = createI18n({
      locale: "nl",
      allowComposition: true,
      warnHtmlInMessage: "off",
      fallbackLocale: "nl",
      messages: {
        en,
        nl,
      },
    });
    export default i18n;
```

This is being used by my main.ts

```
    import { createApp } from "vue";
    import axios from "axios";
    import App from "@/App.vue";
    import router from "@/router";
    import appSettings, { type iAppSettings } from "@/plugin/appSettings";
    import api from "@/plugin/api";
    import i18n from "@/i18n";
    import pinia from "@/stores";
    
    const startUp = async () => {
      try {
        let settings = null;
        const result = await axios.get("config/config.json");
        settings = result.data;
        console.debug("Loaded Config  : ", settings);
    
        const app = createApp(App);
        app.use(pinia);
        app.use(router);
        app.use(appSettings, settings);
        app.use(api, settings?.apiUrl);
        app.use(i18n);
    
        app.mount("#app");
    
        // change locale via `global` property, this should work according to the documentation but it does not.
        i18n.global.locale = "en";

        //Also not working
        i18n.global.locale.value = "en";
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("start up fail", e);
      }
    };
    startUp()
      .then(
        () => {
          console.debug("Application mounted");
        },
        (e) => {
          console.error("start up fail", e);
        }
      )
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error("start up fail", e);
      });
```

According to the documentation I could use the $i18n variable in my Composition API components.

```
    
    import { useAppSettings } from "@/plugin/appSettings";
    import { ref } from "vue";
    import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
    
    const props = defineProps({
      year: { type: Number, required: true },
      currentYear: { type: Number, required: true },
    });
    
    const appSettings = useAppSettings();
    const { t } = useI18n();
    
    const year = ref(11);
    year.value = props.year.toString();
    
    if (props.currentYear > 2022) {
      year.value += " - " + props.currentYear;
    }
    
    //Object is possibly undefined on this
    this.$i18n
    
    //$i18n is undefined
    $i18n
```

Also tried this in my component template but sadly also not working, like mentioned here https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/scope.html#global-scope-1

Answer (score 5):

Solved it myself, I needed the remove the brackets. Not sure what these brackets do, if somebody could explain to me or has a good resource where I can read up on this matter would be appreciated.

```
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
const { t } = useI18n();
```

```
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
const t = useI18n();
t.locale.value = "en";
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

1. `i18n.global.locale = "en"` not working

This might be an error in documentation because `i18.global.locale` is a `ref` ([WritableComputedRef](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#locale) to be precise ) so correct way is actually `i18n.global.locale.value = 'en'` (works in my application)

2. `$i18n` is undefined

This is because all component data/methods etc. (Options API) outside of templates must be used with `this.` - so `this.$i18n.locale` should work

Comment: i18n.global.locale.value = 'en' after the app.mount gives the following error "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)". the this.$i18n.locale is also not working I'm getting the error Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532) on the this keyword. Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm using composion api for my components.

Comment: As I said, it works exactly this in my app. Vue i18n 9.1.10. If you want to use Composition API, you must initialize i18n with `legacy: false` - [docs](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#basic-usage)